Fix Babel "regeneratorRuntime not defined" without creating import
We currently have the problem that our website is throwing the error regeneratorruntime is not defined.
After searching through some and other  SO threads, I always get Cannot use import statement outside a module or require is not defined errors when trying to use their solutions.
This is our config.js:
module.exports = {
  ignore: ["src/js/ts-build/**/*.js"],
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        modules: false,
        debug: false,
        targets: {
          ie: "11",
          chrome: 67,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};


